# Created two Lists from same pojo array, Modifying one List, same thing affects on other list also

Tags: java, android, arrays

I have created two lists object from the same pojo and sorted one of them. When I tried to change one list, other lists also got updated.

```
List<FilterPojo.Data> filterList = new ArrayList<>();
List<FilterPojo.Data> subFilterList = new ArrayList<>();
```

If I change the value in `filterList`, same changes occur in `subFilterList`

Comment: Please post the code of how you make these changes.

Comment: filterList.get(position).setIsSelect(!filterList.get(position).getIsSelect()); if i cange the value in filter list it also affect subFilterList

Comment: How are you populating these lists, post the complete code

Comment: It would be great if you can post some code, to me it seems like, assumption, your both lists using the same object reference.

Comment: s both lists uses the same object

Answer (score 2):

With the limited information that is provided by you, it seems you are creating/populating `subFilterList` as `subList` of `filterList`. When you do that, all changes made in either of the list will be reflected in other.

This happens because `List.subList()`, returns a view of the list, so modifications to the original list will be reflected in the sub-list. As suggested by others, instead of `subList` use `addAll` to populate `subFilterList`

Answer (score 1):

This could be reference problem. Lists maintains their references when items are copied to other list, if you do something like:

```
List<FilterPojo.Data> subFilterList = filterList;
```

Use `addAll` method instead,

```
subFilterList.clear();
subFilterList.addAll(filterList);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try below

```
        List<String> filterList = new ArrayList<String>();
        List<String> subFilterList = new ArrayList<String>();

        filterList.add("A");
        filterList.add("B");
        filterList.add("C");

        /*subFilterList = filterList; // reference to same object , change will reflect in both
        filterList.add("C");
        System.out.println(filterList);
        System.out.println(subFilterList);*/

        subFilterList.addAll(filterList);   
        filterList.add("C");
        System.out.println(filterList);
        System.out.println(subFilterList);
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly the context that you are asking. 
Your lists are holding the same object. For example, in this case p1.

```
Person p1 = new Person();
List<Person> list1 = new ArrayList<Person>();
list1.add(p1);
List<Person> list2 = new ArrayList<Person>();
list2.add(p1);
p1.setName("new name");
```